# combine two URL into one in angular2 - ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to combine two urls into a single url.

```
let url = "http://example.com/public/";
```

and I have file in path `"/samples/leads/Import_Leads_Sample.csv"` which is coming from API. I am taking this in one subscript as `filepath` now filepath holds the

```
 filepath: "/samples/leads/Import_Leads_Sample.csv"
```

I want both this to be combined and form one URL as.

```
let url = "http://example.com/public/samples/leads/Import_Leads_Sample.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the filepath in a variable and combine both variables.

```
let url = "http://example.com/public/";
let filepath = Object.filepath; // equals "/samples/leads/Import_Leads_Sample.csv"

let finalUrl = url + filepath.substr(1); // substr(1) to remove the '/' and avoid having a final url with '//' in it
```

Comment: `Object {filepath: "/samples/leads/Import_Leads_Sample.csv"}`  this is how I am getting from API. And after following your steps I am getting as `http://example.com/public/[object Object]`

Comment: Because in the variable `filepath` you have to store the string that you get from the API call. Check my update, now `filepath` equals the string url from your API response Object.

Comment: @AkashM check my answer's update. The thing is that you need to store the url in a variable as a string, not an object. So, navigate the object to retrieve the string and store it in a variable. That is what I have done in my answer, asuming the that the object that has the API's response is `Object`. But you did not provide full code or anything so I did my best with what I had. Cheers! ;)

Comment: Yes I stringify it using `JSON.stringify(obj);` and followed your steps and it worked. Thank you @SrAxi

Comment: @AkashM I'm glad to help. It's always a huge pleasure being able to help others. Good luck in your project mate! There you have my +1! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. I facing another issue which is also an part of this question. If you are interested in solving that please have look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736485/download-csv-file-with-angular-2-ionic-2  I am new to ionic2 and angular2. Thank you.